# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The platform "0" does not appear to have been added to this project

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I created an ionic project like ionic documentation said

1. $ ionic start HelloWorld blank
2. $ cd HelloWorld
3. $ ionic serve
4. Install the Camera Plugins

   - npm install @ionic-native/camera --save
   - ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
   - Add Plugins to Your App's Module

     import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';
     @NgModule({
       providers: [
         Camera
       ]
     })
     export class AppModule { }

when run project on a device using command  ionic Cordova run android --device 0
I got this error

> cordova run android 0 --device
>   Android Studio project detected

```
(node:17224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The platform "0" does not appear to have been added to this project.
    at Object.getPlatformApi (C:\Users\m.besher\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\platforms\platforms.js:46:15)
    at C:\Users\m.besher\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\prepare.js:54:38
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\m.besher\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\prepare.js:52:47
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\m.besher\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\m.besher\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\m.besher\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
    at C:\Users\m.besher\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
    at flush (C:\Users\m.besher\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
(node:17224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of
an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17224) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that
are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?
```

Comment: `ionic cordova run android --device 0` delete the `0`

Comment: thanks it's working with me